# Am I hellbanned?

Tags: support, banning

Could you please check for me if I got a hellban on SO? I'm starting to get worried since I flagged my own question to a moderator and the conversation didn't go so well. After that I don't receive attention from the site. Did I get a hellban?

Comment: There are not any blocks whatsoever on your account, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: According to MSE's tag info for [meta-tag:hellban], such a ban does not exist.

Comment: @animuson Thanks , I was just.... Confused. No one reply me lol. Lots of things are changing in my life now, So I'm just not sure what's going on. Please accept my apology for wasting your time.

Answer (score 15):

If you're banned, you'll know about it.

From [Is there going to be a process around hellbanning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93806):

> Hellbanning, slowbanning, errorbanning, and randombanning are all
>   things we have never experimented with and do not intend to.
>
> It is very hard to make the argument that using extreme evil to battle
>   evil makes the internet better.
>
> Our current measures of banning and stopping the huge flow of extreme
>   low quality posts seem to be doing fine. In fact, I think we are doing
>   way better than we were 3 months ago.
>
> We also seem to be fine dealing with people complaining about "why kan
>   i nt aks Qestion URGNT?".
>
> I think we can stop the flow of crap by improving our existing
>   systems, while being transparent about what it is we are doing.
>
> When we stop people from asking questions, we stop them from asking
>   questions; we do not put them in a virtual reality sandbox.